# PageReference.getContent() returning error 'System.CalloutException: Callout loop not allowed

Tags: callout

I am receiving the following error 'Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: System.CalloutException: Callout loop not allowed'. My code is as follows:

```
pageReference pdf = Page.viewPDF;
pdf.getParameters().put('id',commDocIds[0]);
Attachment attach = new Attachment();
Blob body;
body = pdf.getContent();
```

And this code is inside a loop. I thought that only soql and dml isn't allow in loop, but now this weird error. How can i solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no solution yet. As of Summer 15, Salesforce have implemented a critical update 
PageReference getContent() and getContentAsPDF() Methods Treated as Callouts". If enabled, the following error will be raised: "(304497466)|FATAL_ERROR|System.CalloutException: Callout loop not allowed"

A ***temporary*** workaround might be to deactivate the Critical Update.

```
Setup > Build > Critical Updates
```

A similar question was raised on [Salesforce Discussion Forum](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BP6DIAW).

Comment: For the time being, i think that disabling the critical updates is sufficient for me. Thanks